# Group by and select lowest

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the non repeated records of my database, and if there is one repeated, choose the one with the soonest date. To do so, I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT name, MIN(date) FROM `table` GROUP BY number_offer ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

and then, showing them like this:

```
echo $row['fecha'];
echo $row['name'];
```

The query selects correctly all the non repeated records but fails at selecting the sooner date (it says 'undefined index "date"'). Do you have any idea of how to do that?

Comment: do you want to order by `MIN(date)`?

Comment: I am trying to select the non repeated records of my database, and if there is one repeated, choose the one with the min date.

Comment: Min(date) as date

Comment: `SELECT name, MIN(date) as adate FROM table GROUP BY name ORDER BY adate ASC`  use an alias to the column min(date)

Comment: Why are you grouping by a different column from the one you're selecting? Is there a 1-to-1 correspondence between `number_offer` and `name`? If not, you'll get a random `name` from the `number_offer` group.

Comment: just remove min() function befoure date it's retun 0 /1

Comment: @NavnitMishra If he removes `min()` then he won't get the lowest date like he wants.

Comment: dear he can use desc and lim it for this

Comment: @NavnitMishra That will return the lowest date in the whole table, not in each group.

Comment: @NavnitMishra `MIN(date)` is exactly correct for getting the lowest date in each group. I don't know why you think it's wrong.

Comment: check query first and set return type

Comment: Thank you all for you answers. @Strawberry and IvoP your solutions worked for me. If you could make a complete answer I will accept it

Comment: This amounts to little more than a simple typographical error, so it doesn't in my view warrant an answer, and should be closed accordingly. Others obviously disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the index fail is related  to  a missing alias

```
SELECT name, MIN(date) as `date`
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY number_offer 
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

but you are select for name and grouping by number_offer ..the select for column not aggreation function and not in group by is deprecated
in sql starting recent db version

you should re evaluate you query using proper group by eg:

if you are select name you should group by name (and not number_offer)

```
SELECT name, MIN(date) 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `MIN(date) as datee` or `MIN(date) datee`